# Import field defintions in Filemaker 12

Tags: filemaker

I need to define several hundred similar fields in Filemaker 12 (calculating dates in Jan 2010, February 2010 ... November 2025, December 2025) and have created the field definitions in an Excel file. Instead of cutting and pasting them individually into each new field definition box, is there a way to import the file at one time? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear. In general, if you choose to import into a new table, fields will be created automatically for you.

That said, I would urge you to reconsider your structure, as having "several hundred similar fields" is almost certainly a mistake that will limit what you can do further down the line. I strongly suspect you should have multiple records instead of multiple fields.

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do: I have 250,000 records updated weekly that represent projects, each with a start and end date for each of two phases, as well as the names of the people in charge of each phase. I currently have fields for "Phase 1 during January 2015" (phase 1 starts before 2/1/16 and ends after 12/31/14); "Phase 1 during February 2015" (phase 1 starts before 3/1/16 and ends after 1/31/15);  etc. I've got 24 fields (2 phases for 2015) used to calculate monthly work load, but want to compare to past and future loads. Do I have to manually define 24 fields for each year? Thanks!

Comment: @MartyR It depends on how exactly the "monthly work load" is calculated. Do you calculate the actual number of days a project spans in each month? Also, how many months at most do you expect to view?

Comment: I'm only diving down to the month level (not the days within the month), so just want to know how many projects each person has in each month.I want to go back at least 5 years and I'm preparing to go forward at least ten. Again, this works perfectly for this year and I can manually define the past and future field calculations, but it would be easier to just import the definitions if possible. Thanks.

Comment: @MartyR **1.** It's not possible to import calculation field formulas. **2.** As I stated in my answer, I don't think you're headed in a good direction. I would like to offer you a better one, but I don't fully follow your description (this is the first time you mention persons being involved). ... {cont.)

Comment: ... Still, I am quite  sure you should have a table where each month (or person/month) would be a **record**, and the number of the projects overlapping that month would be determined by counting the related records.. I am also quite sure that no human can absorb 15*12 month data at once, so I would use a global year field to select which period to view.